# Entity Framework constraints cardinality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0

How can I make a constraint on Entity Framework to read a foreign key relation from table cars to vehicle (for example) as `0..1 -> 1` instead of `* -> 1`?

I have tables

```
create TABLE [dbo].[Vehicles](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
  <rest of the columns>
)

create TABLE [dbo].[Cars](
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
  <rest of the columns>
)
```

and foreign key:

```
alter table [Cars] add foreign key(id) references [Vehicles](id)
```

when I create a model from the DB, it is created as `* -> 1` an I cant change:

[image]

I know I manually change the association between the two entities but it doesn't matter because it doesn't change the constraint

I need to do that to set the baseType property of `Cars` to `Vehicle` to Implement a Inheritance.

Currently I'm getting this error:

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'BoatsTPT' in relationship
>   'FK__BoatsTPT__Id__117F9D94'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the
>   key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent
>   Role must be 1.

Comment: Could it be that you have the PK of Cars set to be a FK to the PK of the Vehicle's table and both cannot be NULL.
If you made the Vehicle[Id] a seperate column on the Cars table it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first make `Id` column in your `Cars` table a primary key otherwise it is not one-to-one relation.

Comment: perfect, I missed that. Thanks